# How does kubernetes replication controller handle data?

Tags: kubernetes

If I setup a replication controller for something like a database, how does it keep the data in the replicas in-sync? If one of the replica goes down, how does it bring it back up with the latest data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A replication controller ensures that the desired number of pods with the same template are kept running in the system. The replication controller itself does not know anything about what it is running, and doesn't have any special hooks for containers running databases. This means that if you want to run a container with a database with more than one replica, then it is easiest to run a database that can natively do replication and discovery (possibly with the injection of some environment variables).

An alternative is to run a pod with two containers, where one container is a vanilla database, and the second "side-car" container is used to implement the necessary replication / synchronization / master election or whatever extra functionality you need to provide to make the database run in a clustered environment. This is more flexible (you can run a database that wasn't initially designed to run in a clustered environment) but also requires more custom work to make it scale.

Comment: So, when a pod or a container goes down, it creates a new one from the template with the initial (or no data) as in the template?

Comment: Yes. When new pods are created they are created fresh. If you want to persist data you should look at using persistent volumes (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/volumes.md).